# MaterialUI component as Addon in vaadin 7

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, vaadin7

For my work in vaadin 7, I need to connect a Slider from MaterialUI.
The vaadin component.Slider is not suitable, because I need to set the color of the slider, labels from Java code, change the design styles and the color of the slider depending on the value (in the example, 3 colors and the slider on the green label should be green, yellow on yellow, and so on)
[image: Slider example]

I have already added to the addon babel.min.js , react.production.min.js , react-dom.production.min.js , material-ui.production.min.js the latest versions as files. Everything that is specified in the [material-ui example CDN started](https://mui.com/material-ui/getting-started/installation/)

The addon was created according to the description from [adding JS as addon vaadin 7](https://vaadin.com/docs/v7/framework/gwt/gwt-javascript)

Java class example

```
@JavaScript({
    "vaadin://addons/materialui/resources/js/babel.min.js",
    "vaadin://addons/materialui/resources/js/react.production.min.js",
    "vaadin://addons/materialui/resources/js/react-dom.production.min.js",
    "vaadin://addons/materialui/resources/js/material-ui.production.min.js",
    "vaadin://addons/materialui/resources/js/sliderComponent.jsx",
    "vaadin://addons/materialui/resources/js/materialui-connector.js",})
@StyleSheet("vaadin://addons/materialui/resources/css/materialui.css")
public class MaterialUI extends AbstractJavaScriptComponent {

public MaterialUI() {
    addStyleName("v-materialui");
}


@Override
protected MaterialUIState getState() {
    return (MaterialUIState) super.getState();
}
```

}

But then I have a stupor. In the connector, I tried to write as in the examples, directly. I tried to create my own file.js in the code was extends React.Component. Each time it ended with an error on an unidentified character '<' or on the use of an undefined ReactDOM.

The last attempt returns no errors, but gives no result at all [materialui-connector.js]:

```
window.ru_rlisystems_web_platform_addons_materialui_MaterialUI = function() {
    let element = this.getElement();

    let rootEl = document.createElement("rootMUI");
    element.appendChild(rootEl);
    let importScript = document.createElement("script");
    importScript.type = 'text/babel';
    importScript.innerHTML = 'const {\n' +
        '    Slider,\n' +
        '    Box\n' +
        '  } = MaterialUI;\n' +
        '\n' +
        '  const marks = [\n' +
        '    {\n' +
        '        value: 0,\n' +
        '        label: \'0°C\',\n' +
        '    },\n' +
        '    {\n' +
        '        value: 20,\n' +
        '        label: \'20°C\',\n' +
        '    },\n' +
        '    {\n' +
        '        value: 37,\n' +
        '        label: \'37°C\',\n' +
        '    },\n' +
        '    {\n' +
        '        value: 100,\n' +
        '        label: \'100°C\',\n' +
        '    },\n' +
        '];\n' +
        '\n' +
        'function valuetext(value) {\n' +
        '    return `${value}°C`;\n' +
        '}\n' +
        '\n' +
        '  // Create a theme instance.\n' +
        '  const theme = createTheme({\n' +
        '    palette: {\n' +
        '      primary: {\n' +
        '        main: \'#556cd6\',\n' +
        '      },\n' +
        '      secondary: {\n' +
        '        main: \'#19857b\',\n' +
        '      },\n' +
        '      error: {\n' +
        '        main: colors.red.A400,\n' +
        '      },\n' +
        '    },\n' +
        '  });\n' +
        '\n' +
        '  function App() {\n' +
        '    return (\n' +
        '        <Box sx={{ width: 300 }}>\n' +
        '        <Slider\n' +
        '        aria-label="Small steps"\n' +
        '        defaultValue={20}\n' +
        '        getAriaValueText={valuetext}\n' +
        '        step={1}\n' +
        '        marks\n' +
        '        min={0}\n' +
        '        max={100}\n' +
        '        valueLabelDisplay="on"/>\n' +
        '    </Box>\n' +
        '    );\n' +
        '  }\n' +
        '\n' +
        '  const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById(\'rootMUI\'));\n' +
        '  root.render(\n' +
        '      <App />\n' +
        '  );';

    element.appendChild(importScript);

    this.onStateChange = function() {

    }

};
```

I tried to put the render in a separate file and connect it via @JavaScript, but I get the error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at
> sliderComponent.jsx:32:9)

```
const { React } = require('./react.production.min')
const {
    Slider,
    Box
} = require('material-ui.production.min')

const marks = [
    {
        value: 0,
        label: '0°C',
    },
    {
        value: 20,
        label: '20°C',
    },
    {
        value: 37,
        label: '37°C',
    },
    {
        value: 100,
        label: '100°C',
    },
];

function valuetext(value) {
    return `${value}°C`;
}

function App() {
    return (
        <Box sx={{ width: 300 }}>
            <Slider
                aria-label="Small steps"
                defaultValue={20}
                getAriaValueText={valuetext}
                step={1}
                marks
                min={0}
                max={100}
                valueLabelDisplay="on"/>
        </Box>
    );
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('rootMUI'));
root.render(
    <App />
);
```

Is there any chance of using this library in vaadin 7? Or maybe there are examples and libraries easier to achieve my goals?

Comment: You probably have typo in your scrupt, it is hard to see as there is no syntax highlighting. I recommend to import it from file using `@JavaScript` instead.

Comment: But how? I get an error either on import or "Unexpected token '<'". Maybe it's possible to see an example somewhere?

Comment: Does that sliderComponent exists as pure js file instead of jsx? In Vaadin 7 the toolchain is not based on node and webpack, hence it cannot convert jsx to js.